# jQuery Browser Auto Scroll With Navigation?

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

Is it possible, or does anyone know of a tutorial where you have a fixed navigation with a click to scroll to a section of the page, and the navigation indicates your at that point with an active class?

Similar to this but with the navigation fixed at the top..

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/WebsiteScrolling/index_vertical.html

Is it just a case of adding an active class to the navigation, then somehow telling jquery to add it on click?

I have defiantly seen a tutorial for it in the past but cannot find :(

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for but this is a cool fixed navigation plugin:

http://christophercliff.github.com/sausage/

Check out an example here: http://christophercliff.github.com/sausage/examples/couchdb.html

Comment: Thanks this is kind of what i'm after, navigation different and put at the top, but editable i'm sure.

Thanks for both your inputs :)

Comment: Thats not what i'm after actually, too complex doesnt need to be infinity scroll.

This site basically does what i'm after perfectly, cannot find tutorial on it though :( www.fullstopinteractive.com/